# Python parallel computing using joblib

Tags: python, numpy, parallel-processing, joblib

I am having issues trying to get my parallel processing to work in a function that can be called from the command line. The function downloads data from a website, does some processing and saves the data to disk, so multiprocessing seemed to be an obvious solution. When I try to run the function, however, it creates idle python processes and freezes, not sure what I am doing wrong.  Currently I am using python 2.7 (64bit) with 64bit windows 7 and joblib to preform the task.

Here is a simplified code that reproduces the problem:

```
import os,numpy as np
from joblib import Parallel, delayed

def foo(stations,wdir,multiprocess):
    if multiprocess==False:
        for a in stations:
            writefoo(wdir,a)
    if multiprocess==True:
        Parallel(n_jobs=len(stations))(delayed(writefoo)(wdir,station) for station in stations)

def writefoo(wdir,station):
    os.makedirs(os.path.join(wdir,station[0]))
    np.save(os.path.join(wdir,station[0],station[0]),station[1])

def go(multiprocess):
    stations=[['ST1',np.random.rand(1,1000).flatten()],['ST2',
               np.random.rand(1,1000).flatten()],['ST3',np.random.rand(1,1000).flatten()]]
    wdir=os.getcwd()
    foo(stations,wdir,multiprocess)
```

Now when I type go(True) from an ipython console 3 new python processes are created that do not use any % cpu and about the same amount of memory (16 mb) but do not create the files and just sit until I kill them.

When I run go(False) the function takes only a few ms to run and operates as expected, but sequentially rather than in parallel. What am I doing wrong here?
Note: It is important that the entire process can be called from the command line rather than running the script itself because the code is to be used in a module.

Comment: Multiprocessing can *only* help with *CPU*-bound tasks - it won't help you if you really are IO-bound.

Comment: Sorry, I should have been more specific. During the time in which the data is being downloaded from the internet I am not IO bound, nor during the time in which the data processing is being performed. I know multiprocessing will help because I see significant speed up when I run the same function in different consoles passing a chunk of the problem to each through some very blunt methods. As you can image this is not a suitable approach

Comment: Your example code executes almost instantaneously on my machine, regardless of whether `multiprocess` is `True` or `False` (~123ms with multiprocessing, ~1.71ms without). Can you confirm that you are seeing the problem you describe for the exact code that you posted?

Comment: Yes, after running the exact code above then running go(True) the problem I described above occurs. Are you running Windows 7, python 2.7x, and using an ipython console?

Comment: When I use a normal python console I get the following for each poolworker :    tracebacks:Process PoolWorker-1:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Anaconda\lib\multiprocessing\process.py", line 258, in _bootstrap
    self.run()
  File "C:\Anaconda\lib\multiprocessing\process.py", line 114, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "C:\Anaconda\lib\multiprocessing\pool.py", line 102, in worker
    task = get()
  File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\joblib\pool.py", line 341, in get
    return recv()
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'writefoo'

Comment: This looks like a problem with joblib itself. I suspect you'll see the same error if you replace the body of `writefoo` with `pass`.

Comment: @ ali_m you are correct, I get the same result when I replace the body of writefoo with pass

Comment: I'm happy to try and help you diagnose the problem with joblib, but it the comments are really not the best place for this. Unfortunately I can't invite you to chat since you have <20 rep (a pretty self-defeating rule...). Hopefully someone will upvote one of your questions, or you could try and gain some more rep by providing answers or suggesting edits ([see here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation)).

Comment: how many processes are you creating  - a thousand? my understanding is that there should be roughly speaking no more processes than cores.